# How to Sort array alphabetical and by strlen

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am looking for the cleanest ways to sort array alphabetically and by strlen in PHP. The cleanest way i came up with to sort by strlen is this:

```
array_multisort(array_map('strlen', $array), $array);
```

How would i extend this to sort alphabetically by values as the primary sorting?

This is an example array:

```
array('name'=>'Firstname','name2'=>'Lastname1','name3'=>'Lastname2')
```

The order after the sort function is not important, what is important is that it always returns the same order when sorted, regardless the same length of some values. The array keys are not needed after sort.

Comment: Great question! But could you please provide an example array, with an example output of how it should look after sorting?

Comment: I answered before seeing your edit. Do you need to preserve the array keys? If so, then do you need to keep the keys associated with their original values and just reorder their positioning, or does that not matter?

Comment: No, the array keys are not needed after sort. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `usort()`:

```
$your_array = array( . . . );
$your_compare_function = function($elem1, $elem2) {
    return strlen($elem1) > strlen($elem2) || $elem1 > $elem2;
};

usort($your_array, $your_compare_function);
```

If the sort order is incorrect, I apologize. I'm not sure from your post what the intended ordering is. Just update the compare function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You either want `sort()` or `natsort()` (if you are dealing with multi-digit numbers in your strings).

There will be no tie in `sort()` or `natsort()` that will be "broken" by using `strlen()`.

The answer is: Don't bother with `strlen()` as a second comparison and `usort()` is overkill.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bfe72c41ed69d552f898868c4d0e2d26868f4cab))

```
$array=['name'=>'Firstname','name2'=>'Lastname10','name3'=>'Lastname2','name4'=>'Lastname1','name4'=>'Lastname20'];
natsort($array);
var_export($array);

echo "\n---\n";

sort($array);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'name' => 'Firstname',
  'name3' => 'Lastname2',
  'name2' => 'Lastname10',
  'name4' => 'Lastname20',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'Firstname',
  1 => 'Lastname10',
  2 => 'Lastname2',
  3 => 'Lastname20',
)
```